# Second monitor and workspaces

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

When my second monitor is connected to my system, I get four workspaces for each.  This is annoying as I now have eight.

I would like to continue using workspaces on my large monitor but have the second sitting only with a single workspace.

Is this possible?
If so, how?

Comment: Are you using Unity? And do you mean that the same contents are displayed on the second monitor as on the first? Or the contents are somehow different?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First you can quickly know how many workspaces you have with the following commands, open a terminal and type:

```
dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/hsize
dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/vsize
```

It should return 2 for both if you have 4 workspaces.

Now with an external monitor, you don't really have 8 workspaces even if this kind of picture can be confusing because both screen are creating an extended desktop (if you are not mirroring), a workspace is delimited here by the orange line:

[image]

To answer your question, there's no way to specify the number of workspaces per display (the unity plugin only store global values) but you can force a given window to stay always on visible workspace. I often do that for my mail client that I left on my laptop monitor. It's like having a single workspace. Just click the title bar of your application and select "Always on visible workspace":

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So simple, yet exactly what I wanted! :) A lot better than the suggestion of other answers to install third party software.