# workspace, move current screen but not the others

Tags: 16.04, unity, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I'd like to use a workspace and connect a monitor to the computer, to play a movie on it for example.

Is it possible to switch workspace in the current screen only, in order to let the monitor locked to the same application ?

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks

EDIT: using Unity

Comment: found https://askubuntu.com/questions/449040/second-monitor-and-workspaces , should do the trick. Better idea ?